# Trying to return specific value from API call based on user input

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, utf-8, decodable

I'm trying to pull data from an API based on the word a user inputs. Right now, I can run this

```
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("APPID", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-app-id")
        request.addValue("APPKEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-app-key")
        
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = postData
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
                do {
                    let macros = try JSONDecoder().decode(Instruction.self, from: data)
                    
                    print(macros)
                    
                }
                catch {
                    print(error)
                }
```

And if the user inputs "banana", it prints the below result. I only want the macro numbers (protein, carbs, fats, calories). Is there a way to pull only those from the API call? Below the print are my Codable structs as well if that helps.

`Instruction(foods: [Multiple_Views.Food(foodName: "banana", brandName: nil, servingQty: 1, servingUnit: "medium (7\" to 7-7/8\" long)", servingWeightGrams: 118.0, nfCalories: 105.02, nfTotalFat: 0.39, nfSaturatedFat: 0.13, nfCholesterol: 0.0, nfSodium: 1.18, nfTotalCarbohydrate: 26.95, nfDietaryFiber: 3.07, nfSugars: 14.43, nfProtein: 1.29, nfPotassium: 422.44, nfP: 25.96, fullNutrients: [Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 203, value: 1.2862), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 204, value: 0.3894), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 205, value: 26.9512), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 207, value: 0.9676), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 208, value: 105.02), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 209, value: 6.3484), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 210, value: 2.8202), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 211, value: 5.8764), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 212, value: 5.723), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 213, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 214, value: 0.0118), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 221, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 255, value: 88.3938), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 262, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 263, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 268, value: 437.78), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 269, value: 14.4314), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 287, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 291, value: 3.068), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 301, value: 5.9), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 303, value: 0.3068), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 304, value: 31.86), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 305, value: 25.96), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 306, value: 422.44), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 307, value: 1.18), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 309, value: 0.177), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 312, value: 0.092), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 313, value: 2.596), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 315, value: 0.3186), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 317, value: 1.18), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 318, value: 75.52), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 319, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 320, value: 3.54), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 321, value: 30.68), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 322, value: 29.5), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 323, value: 0.118), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 324, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 328, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 334, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 337, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 338, value: 25.96), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 341, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 342, value: 0.0236), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 343, value: 0.0118), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 344, value: 0.0708), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 345, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 346, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 347, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 401, value: 10.266), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 404, value: 0.0366), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 405, value: 0.0861), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 406, value: 0.7847), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 410, value: 0.3941), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 415, value: 0.4331), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 417, value: 23.6), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 418, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 421, value: 11.564), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 429, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 430, value: 0.59), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 431, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 432, value: 23.6), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 435, value: 23.6), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 454, value: 0.118), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 501, value: 0.0106), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 502, value: 0.033), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 503, value: 0.033), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 504, value: 0.0802), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 505, value: 0.059), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 506, value: 0.0094), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 507, value: 0.0106), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 508, value: 0.0578), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 509, value: 0.0106), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 510, value: 0.0555), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 511, value: 0.0578), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 512, value: 0.0909), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 513, value: 0.0472), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 514, value: 0.1463), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 515, value: 0.1794), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 516, value: 0.0448), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 517, value: 0.033), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 518, value: 0.0472), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 601, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 605, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 606, value: 0.1322), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 607, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 608, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 609, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 610, value: 0.0012), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 611, value: 0.0024), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 612, value: 0.0024), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 613, value: 0.1204), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 614, value: 0.0059), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 617, value: 0.026), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 618, value: 0.0543), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 619, value: 0.0319), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 620, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 621, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 626, value: 0.0118), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 627, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 628, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 629, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 630, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 631, value: 0.0), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 636, value: 18.88), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 645, value: 0.0378), Multiple_Views.FullNutrient(attrID: 646, value: 0.0861)], nixBrandName: nil, nixBrandID: nil, nixItemName: nil, nixItemID: nil, upc: nil, consumedAt: "2022-03-31T17:14:17+00:00", metadata: Multiple_Views.Metadata(isRawFood: false), source: 1, ndbNo: 9040, tags: Multiple_Views.Tags(item: "banana", measure: nil, quantity: "1.0", foodGroup: 3, tagID: 399), altMeasures: [Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 225.0, measure: "cup, mashed", seq: Optional(1), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 150.0, measure: "cup, sliced", seq: Optional(2), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 81.0, measure: "extra small (less than 6\" long)", seq: Optional(3), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 101.0, measure: "small (6\" to 6-7/8\" long)", seq: Optional(4), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 118.0, measure: "medium (7\" to 7-7/8\" long)", seq: Optional(5), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 136.0, measure: "large (8\" to 8-7/8\" long)", seq: Optional(6), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 152.0, measure: "extra large (9\" or longer)", seq: Optional(7), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 126.0, measure: "NLEA serving", seq: Optional(8), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 28.35, measure: "oz", seq: Optional(80), qty: 1), Multiple_Views.AltMeasure(servingWeight: 100.0, measure: "g", seq: nil, qty: 100)], lat: nil, lng: nil, mealType: 3, photo: Multiple_Views.Photo(thumb: "https://nix-tag-images.s3.amazonaws.com/399_thumb.jpg", highres: "https://nix-tag-images.s3.amazonaws.com/399_highres.jpg", isUserUploaded: false), subRecipe: nil, classCode: nil, brickCode: nil, tagID: nil)])`

Codable Structs here:

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let greeting: String
    let instructions: [Instruction]
}

// MARK: - Instruction
struct Instruction: Codable {
    let foods: [Food]
}

// MARK: - Food
struct Food: Codable {
    let foodName: String
    let brandName: JSONNull?
    let servingQty: Int
    let servingUnit: String
    let servingWeightGrams: Double
    let nfCalories: Double
    let nfTotalFat: Double
    let nfSaturatedFat: Double
    let nfCholesterol: Double
    let nfSodium: Double
    let nfTotalCarbohydrate: Double
    let nfDietaryFiber: Double
    let nfSugars: Double
    let nfProtein: Double
    let nfPotassium: Double
    let nfP: Double
    let fullNutrients: [FullNutrient]
    let nixBrandName, nixBrandID, nixItemName, nixItemID: JSONNull?
    let upc: JSONNull?
    let consumedAt: String
    let metadata: Metadata
    let source, ndbNo: Int
    let tags: Tags
    let altMeasures: [AltMeasure]
    let lat, lng: JSONNull?
    let mealType: Int
    let photo: Photo
    let subRecipe, classCode, brickCode, tagID: JSONNull?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case foodName = "food_name"
        case brandName = "brand_name"
        case servingQty = "serving_qty"
        case servingUnit = "serving_unit"
        case servingWeightGrams = "serving_weight_grams"
        case nfCalories = "nf_calories"
        case nfTotalFat = "nf_total_fat"
        case nfSaturatedFat = "nf_saturated_fat"
        case nfCholesterol = "nf_cholesterol"
        case nfSodium = "nf_sodium"
        case nfTotalCarbohydrate = "nf_total_carbohydrate"
        case nfDietaryFiber = "nf_dietary_fiber"
        case nfSugars = "nf_sugars"
        case nfProtein = "nf_protein"
        case nfPotassium = "nf_potassium"
        case nfP = "nf_p"
        case fullNutrients = "full_nutrients"
        case nixBrandName = "nix_brand_name"
        case nixBrandID = "nix_brand_id"
        case nixItemName = "nix_item_name"
        case nixItemID = "nix_item_id"
        case upc
        case consumedAt = "consumed_at"
        case metadata, source
        case ndbNo = "ndb_no"
        case tags
        case altMeasures = "alt_measures"
        case lat, lng
        case mealType = "meal_type"
        case photo
        case subRecipe = "sub_recipe"
        case classCode = "class_code"
        case brickCode = "brick_code"
        case tagID = "tag_id"
    }
}

// MARK: - AltMeasure
struct AltMeasure: Codable {
    let servingWeight: Double
    let measure: String
    let seq: Int?
    let qty: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case servingWeight = "serving_weight"
        case measure, seq, qty
    }
}

// MARK: - FullNutrient
struct FullNutrient: Codable {
    let attrID: Int
    let value: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case attrID = "attr_id"
        case value
    }
}

// MARK: - Metadata
struct Metadata: Codable {
    let isRawFood: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isRawFood = "is_raw_food"
    }
}

// MARK: - Photo
struct Photo: Codable {
    let thumb, highres: String
    let isUserUploaded: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case thumb, highres
        case isUserUploaded = "is_user_uploaded"
    }
}

// MARK: - Tags
struct Tags: Codable {
    let item: String
    let measure: JSONNull?
    let quantity: String
    let foodGroup, tagID: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case item, measure, quantity
        case foodGroup = "food_group"
        case tagID = "tag_id"
    }
}

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {
    

    static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        // No-op
    }

    init() {}

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have the structures and the API call is working then why not read the values from the properties that interest you? What is the real problem here, what is this question about? Please explain that.

Comment: You are successfully decoding the api response into your structs so I don't understand the question - you already have the data in a usable form?  If you want to avoid all the unwanted properties just remove them from your struct and CodingKeys.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I could just remove properties, I thought everything the API returned had to be defined. Thank you both!

Comment: If you don't define it, the decoder just skips the property.